# ActionScript 3 start drag/sprite weirdness

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a match game, drag and drop a word to a definition. The flow of this game is that after you have answered you click a button and then the game removes the right answers and redisplays the wrong ones.
So far that works, what doesn't is that after the answer portion and I put the wrong words/definitions the drag doesn't "visually" work. when i run in debug the drag is firing, but the object doesn't move on the screen. it also doesn't hit any target (which seems obvious). I never destroy the object.So As far as I can see the mouse events should still be working.

example can be found here:
http://www.pandabrand.net/xmldisplay.html

thanks.
-fw

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some settings on each of those draggable objects aren't being reset. Instead of recycling here, maybe store the wrong answers in an array, destroy the old objects (making sure to remove all listeners) and then recreate everything for the new scene.

Comment: Yeah, so that results in the same behavior. I didn't upload the new code to my site but tested locally I used removeChild() also removed all listeners. Created brand new objects and they react in the same way.

Comment: Probably the most helpful code to supply would be whatever is run between scenes - I'll be able to help you a bit better then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making sure there is not another movie clip on top of the one you want to drag that may be stealing your event.

You can also try to prevent children of your movie clip from stealing events as follows:

whatever_mc.mouseChildren = false;